# Autoincrement colum with existing value from selected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Query to select the rows that will autoincrement column `'invoice_no'`

```
SELECT *FROM oc_order WHERE order_status_id >= 0
GROUP BY order_id;
```

The row with order_id #1276 has `'invoice_no`' value 222

I would like to autoincrement so that the next selected row `id WHERE order_status_id >= 0` will have `'invoice_no'` value 223 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

There's only one scaleable and robust way to do this in MySQL. That's with an `invoice` table containing an autoincrementing column called `invoice_no`. When you need a new unique `invoice_no` value, do this:

```
INSERT INTO invoice (col, col) VALUES (whatever, whatelse)
SET @new_invoice_no := LAST_INSERT_ID()
UPDATE oc_order SET invoice_no = @new_invoice_no  (or whatever)
```

If you try to do this with `SELECT MAX(invoice_no)` or similar, you'll start getting lots of duplicate values when your database gets busy.

Here is a writeup on the topic. http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/unique-numbers-oracle-mysql/